# Need help selecting between the two

Tags: grammar

Should it be an "English Professional Editor" or "Professional English Editor"?

Comment: Are You English or just editing English text?

Comment: Just editing English text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should use 'Professional English Editor'.

'English Professional Editor' implies you are English (i.e. an English national) who is a professional editor.

Comment: But then what is that? A professional who edits English texts or an editor of professional English?